# Firebase A/B test roll out the leader

Tags: android, firebase, ab-testing, firebase-remote-config, firebase-ab-testing

I ran A/B test for one version (1.14) of my app.
There were few parameters and 3 groups (including control group).

After starting the A/B test I've released versions 1.15, 1.16 and 1.17 of the app.

Test found the leader.
My expectation is that after rolling out the leader its config will be applied on all users with that version (only for 1.14).

But actual result is:

1. I click "roll out the leader"
2. Dialog with parameter configs appear (3 parameters)
3. I leave all parameters as "don't change value" except one
4. I redirected to remote config page that is unchanged (parameter that was changed during roll out dialog remains default)

I install release and debug application of that version (1.14) and see that changed parameters doesn't apply.

So looks like nothing happened.

Notice: now I have another running A/B test for versions 1.15, 1.16 and 1.17 based on same parameters as finished A/B test.

Comment: This might be easier to answer if you can show your firebase Remote Config values and how you apply them?

Answer (score 1):

this is actually not an option any more.  when you roll out, you can no longer change individual parameters, as this would essentially make your experiment data obsolete.  the values should all roll out correctly in newer versions.